# MySQL foreign key constrain fails

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL statement :

```
CREATE TABLE RoomType(
    hotelID             SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    name                VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (hotelID, name)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE BookingItem(
    bookingID           SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    roomTypeName        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (bookingID, roomTypeName),
    FOREIGN KEY (roomTypeName) REFERENCES RoomType(name)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And it show errors #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint. 
However when I change the line :

```
PRIMARY KEY (hotelID, name)
```

into

```
PRIMARY KEY (name, hotelID)
```

it works perfectly fine. I dont know what happens here. Can someone explain to me why this happens. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm guessing the foreign key needs to match the *primary* primary key for the foreign table. Remember that a combined primary key is like one big concatenated key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOREIGN KEY` should match either several columns from left most part of the `PRIMARY KEY` or the `PRIMARY KEY` completely.

So in case of `(hotelID, name)` PK you can create a foreign key that refers to `hotelID` or to  `(hotelID, name)`, but not to `name`.

That's what [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) says about that:

> However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.

Comment: So there is no way to add foreign key constraint with 'name' in another table ?

Comment: @themyth92: If there is no `PK` with `name` in its left most part - then no